# Chrome dev tools won't dock, and no docking options exist

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

99% of the time, for any given website or webapp, `Chrome Dev Tools` opens docked by default, and I can click the dock icon and change the dock position if desired.

But there is one webapp I use that launches a window via window.open() with a non-editable url in the address bar. When I hit `F12`, dev tools opens in a separate window. There is no dock icon and no way I can find to get dev tools to dock to the right (or anywhere) with the launched browser window.

[image]

[image]

Note: Supposedly `CTRL+Shift+D` can affect/toggle the docking behavior, but this does nothing in my case.

Is dev tools truly refusing to dock in this situation? Or, where can I find the dock icon? How can I make devtools dock to the right of my browser window?

Comment: This is a *popup*, it can't have devtools docked.

Answer (score 2):

So if you open a tab as a window (I do this a lot in ChromeOS) you will not have docking options.  Click the 3-dot menu -> Open in Chrome and now you will have the options again.

Comment: I don't see that option, you mean the three dots in dev tools?

Comment: Well I use a Chromebook so maybe there is a difference?  No, I meant the 3 dots menu in the upper right of the top window. Maybe it's truly a pop-up you are looking at, and if so @w0xx0m may have the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome browser windows (NOT tabs), right-click on the title bar of the browser window and select Show as tab. Then you can ctrl-shft-I to get dev tools and the docking options will be available.